# Are WINE applications sandboxed?

Tags: wine, security, antivirus

I want to run a small Windows program that has no reputation. I can always scan it, but I can't get feedback from other users on its performance or if it is at all malicious.

Rather than go through the pains of creating a virtual machine, would installing the program in WINE be safe? Would the program be sandboxed from the rest of my system? Can a malicious Windows program even harm a Ubuntu system?